# In Smarty Jquery datepicker is not working in IE only

Tags: jquery, smarty

In Smarty , below code not working in IE

```
$("#from").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    altField: '#from_alt',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    beforeShowDay: nationalDays,
    onSelect: function(from) {

    }     

});
```

In IE Error:
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'jQuery16207033619778684976' of undefined or null reference (jQuery JavaScript Library v1.6.2)